# Kotlin Android Studio - Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type Intent?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am getting this error code while going through Android Studio 3.0 Development Essentials. "Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type Intent?". Not sure why. The above code is what I am currently working with and "Intent" had automatically generated a question mark. The bottom code is what is shown in the book.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if ((requestCode == request_code) && (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)) {
        if (data.hasExtra("returnData")) {
            val returnString = data.extras.getString("returnData")
            textView1.text = returnString
        }
    }
}
```

**Code in book**

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
    if ((requestCode == request_code) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {
        if (data.hasExtra("returnData")) {
            val returnString = data.extras.getString("returnData")
            textView1.text = returnString
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Kotlin are *you* using and what version is _the book_ mentioning? Could it be that the method signatures changed? In `Fragments` the signature is (as of today) `override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {` so it's an Optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error, if you come from Swift, is basically because the signature:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
```

Indicates that the parameter `data` of type `Intent?` is of type "Nullable" (Optional in Swift). Meaning you have to *dereference* the Optional first.

In Kotlin (like in Swift), you do so with the `?` mark.

```
if (data?.something)
```

Means that if data is null, or something is false/null (depending on its type), then the if will *not* enter its block.

same for:

```
if (data?.something && data?.somethingElse)
```

This will not crash if data is null and will only pass the condition if both `something` and `somethingElse` are true (or non-null for non-primitives).

The book is probably referencing an old version of Kotlin or the Kotlin-Android plug-in where the Intent received is *not optional* and therefore cannot be null.

All this is better explained in the [Kotlin Nullability](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) chapter :)

Comment: lol yes, I posted this question before looking at the date of the book and now this is all starting to make sense... I am using old info! Im gonna get a updated book or just do online tutorials...

Comment: Welcome to the Android world! A sea of frustration awaits, but also a lot of "I wish I could do that on iOS" with it :)

Answer (score 1):

You could leverage smart casts, what in this case automatically would cast `Intent?` to `Intent` if you explicitly check for `data != null` before you use `data`.

Otherwise just insert null-safe method invocations like `data?.hasExtra("returnData"))` where needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your `intent` is nullable, you have to access its properties using `?` or check for null before using it:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (data != null && (requestCode == request_code) && (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)) {
        if (data.hasExtra("returnData")) {
            val returnString = data.extras.getString("returnData")
            textView1.text = returnString
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're accessing `hasExtra` on the `data` variable without checking to see if the `data` variable is non-null since you declared `data` as nullable (aka with the `?` appended to the `Intent`), hence you get that error. The solution would be one of the following:

1. Add a safe operator (?.) *(recommended): `data.hasExtra(/* ... */)` -> `data?.hasExtra(/* ... */)`)
2. Add a non-null operator (`!!`) *(not recommended unless you know that the value will *always* be non-null)*: `data.hasExtra(/* ... */)` -> `data!!.hasExtra(/* ... */)`
3. Add a condition to check if `data` is non-null before continuing: `data.hasExtra(/* ... */)`-> `data != null && data.hasExtra(/* ... */)` (Note: Kotlin will automatically treat the value of `data` to be non-null for code inside the `data != null` condition)